# my magento online store does not go to the homepage

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

If i type mydomain.com it shows error that this page is not working, but if i type mydomain.com/index.php  or  mydomain.com/any other pages  it will work fine but mydomain.com will show "mydomain.com is not working".

on firefox it shows "The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

```
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies."
```

please what can i do to correct this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the Magento database

Go to phpmyadmin find the core_config_data table and locate these two fields **web/unsecure/base_url**  **web/secure/base_url** and check whether you have entered correct URL.

restart apache

Clear Cache and cookies.

It will work.